# Como adicionar um evento a todos elementos com a mesma classe?

Tags: javascript

Como faço para adicionar um evento a todos elementos de uma mesma classe?

O código que escrevi não funciona:

```
var tabela = document.querySelectorAll('.status');
for (var i = 0; i <= tabela.length; i++) {
    tabela.addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) {
        event.target.parentNode.remove();
    });
}
```

E recebo o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: tabela.addEventListener is not a function at (arquivo.js).

Comment: tem que fazer `tabela[i].addEvent...` e está indo uma posição a mais... seria `< tabela.length`

Comment: Opa, obrigado! Me ajudou muito! :)

Answer (score 4):

O método [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) retorna um objeto [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList), que não possui o método [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) em seu protótipo. Isso significa que você não pode adicionar um *listener* de evento a todos os elementos de um `NodeList` simultaneamente. Para isso, você deve iterar a cada um deles, adicionando o *listener* a cada elemento.

Você fez a iteração corretamente no seu código, ao usar o laço de repetição `for`. O problema que gera o erro em questão se dá na seguinte linha:

> ```
> tabela.addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) { /* ... */
> ```

Porque `tabela` refere-se ao valor retornado pelo `querySelectorAll`.

Então, conforme inclusive citado por [um dos comentários da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/407962/como-adicionar-um-evento-a-todos-elementos-com-a-mesma-classe/407963#comment798135_407962), você precisa mudar para:

```
// Acessar o elemento da iteração atual.
//    ↓↓↓
tabela[i].addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) { /* ... */
```

Assim, você conseguirá adicionar o listener a cada elemento da `NodeList` individualmente.

---

Você pode, inclusive, utilizar o [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), presente no protótipo do [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList), para fazer isso de um modo mais simples:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.status').forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener('dbclick', (event) => {
    event.target.parentNode.remove();
  })
);
```

Assim você evita possíveis erros no laço `for`, como, por exemplo, usar o operador *menor ou igual a* (`<=`), quando deveria usar o operador *menor que* (`<`).

Veja o porquê do "erro" em usar esse operador:

```js
const els = [1, 2, 3];

for (let i = 0; i <= els.length; i++) {
  console.log(els[i]);
}
```

Será imprimido um `undefined` no final, já que `els[3]` (sendo `3` **igual** ao `length` do *array* `els`) não existe. portanto, ao usar o operador *menor que* (`<`), você evita esse problema.

Comment: Opa, obrigado! Me ajudou muito, agora compreendo melhor onde estava o erro e o porquê :)

Comment: @FilipeFrs, se essa resposta respondeu a sua pergunta, não se esqueça de marcá-la clicando no ícone de _check_ ✔️ abaixo do lugar dos votos. :)