# Imagem clicável redirecional para outra página HTML

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Sou bem iniciante em programação, porém, para treinar estou fazendo um RPG in Browser, e a página inicial é a da escolha de classe, e eu quero que a pessoa escolha, clique na imagem e essa imagem redirecione para uma nova página, utilizando o evento "onclick", dependendo da escolha da pessoa. Seria possível?

```
<html>

<head>

    <title> RPG in Browser </title>

    <link href="../../CSS/Projeto 01/Página 01.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

```
<div id="TabelaCentral">

    <table id="Tabela">

        <tr>

            <td id="Classe"> <b id="Font35"> Mago </b> </td>

            <td id="Classe"> <b id="Font35"> Arqueiro </b> </td>

            <td id="Classe"> <b id="Font35"> Guerreiro </b> </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td> <img src="../../Imagens/Projeto 01/Página 01/Mago.jpg" id="ImagemClasse" onClick="alert ('Clicou')"> </td> 

            <td> <img src="../../Imagens/Projeto 01/Página 01/Arqueiro.jpg" id="ImagemClasse">  </td>   

            <td> <img src="../../Imagens/Projeto 01/Página 01/Guerreiro.jpg" id="ImagemClasse"> </td>

        </tr>



    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Perry, você quer utilizar javascript para isso? Pois não é necessário, só com html você consegue criar uma imagem clicável, com a tag <a> e dentro da mesma a tag <img>.

Comment: tem um jogo que foi escrito somente com javascript, o candybox, que não foi necessário para o desenvolvedor utilizar mais de uma página, talvez você possa escrever tudo em uma página só, e então esconder e exibir o texto de acordo com o que você quer exibir na tela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Não é necessário usar JavaScript nesse caso

Se você só deseja redirecionar para uma outra página, nem sequer precisa de JavaScript, bastando o uso do atributo [`href`](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/html/attributes/a-href-attribute/):

```html
<a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69296">
  <img
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ynld.jpg"
    width="100"
    height="100"
  />
</a>
```

### Caso você queira usar JavaScript mesmo assim

Mas você também pode utilizar JavaScript, se quiser criar um comportamento um pouco mais complexo:

```js
const image = document.querySelector('img');

image.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const { src } = event.target;
  alert(`Atributo de origem da imagem: "${src}".`);

  // Redirecionar para outra página:
  location.replace(src);
});
```

```html
<img
  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ynld.jpg"
  width="100"
  height="100"
/>
```

Note que no exemplo acima, eu não utilizei o atributo nativo do HTML `onclick`, visto que a sua prática não é muito recomendada. Se você quiser seguir as melhores práticas, prefira usar o [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) para adicionar um *listener* de eventos.

Além disso, no exemplo acima, adicionei o *listener* a somente **um** elemento. Isto é, o primeiro elemento encontrado com a *tag* `img`. Se você quiser adicionar o *listener* a múltiplos elementos, [leia essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/407963/69296).

Comment: Por enquanto eu prefiro utilizar o OnClick por ser mais básico e de fácil entendimento, mas obrigado pela resposta. Mas onde eu colocaria a tag <a> ? Como eu preciso que cada classe redirecione para uma página diferente, teria que ser no <td> de cada classe certo? Dai ficaria :

<td> <a href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69296">
  
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ynld.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>

    </a>
</td>

?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
<a href="ENDEREÇO DO SITE"><img src="ENDEREÇO DA IMAGEM"></a>
```